# An alternative to unreal engine

Tags: game-development

I wanted to use unreal engine but after installing it it shows an error-
A video graphics driver 5 is required. I cannot use unreal engine so please tell an alternative to it. And please don't recommend cryengine as I have already tried that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The various Quake engines from id software are all Open Source.

Comment: How do I install it

Comment: Please give a link